# django rest create api to show count of distict field in a model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model named 'person' with some field 'name,family,tel,....'
I want to create an api to show count of distinct family.

my **serializer.py**:

```
class PersonCountSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = 'family'
```

my **view.py**:

```
class PersonCountView(ModelViewSet):
      queryset = Person.objects.all().distinct('family').count
      serializer_class = PersonCountSerializer
```

**urls.py:**

```
router.register(r'personcount', views.PersonCount)
```

And it doesn't work, please help to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: are you got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Person.objects.all().annotate(Count('family',                                         distinct=True))

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer

```
Person.objects.all().values_list('family', flat=True).distinct().count()
```

If you want know more refer the doc [Django query distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)